# Subtype as an Argument of Overridden Method

Tags: scala

Code below does not compile. Why can't I pass in `SomeTypeString` as an argument of overridden method in `SomeInst`?

```java
trait SomeType
abstract class SomeClass[T] {
  def method(someType: SomeType): Unit
}
class SomeTypeString extends SomeType

class SomeInst extends SomeClass[String]() {
  override def method(someType: SomeTypeString): Unit = ???
}
```

Comment: Please update tags with "scala" - not every java developer knows scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instances of a supertype must be replaceable by instances of a subtype without altering the desirable properties of the program. That is the very *definition* of "subtype" using the Liskov Substitution Principle, which gives a behavioral contract-based notion of subtyping that takes aliasing into account.

This means that everywhere I have an instance of `SomeClass` I can also use an instance of `SomeInst`. However, in your example that is not true: if I have an instance `i` of `SomeClass` then I can call `i.method(s)`, where `s` is an instance of `SomeType`. According to the Liskov Substitution Principle, I 
*must* be able to do the same, when I call `ii.method(s)`, where `ii` is an instance of `SomeType`. But I am not allowed to. I am only allowed to pass an instance of `SomeTypeString`.

Ergo, your example violates the Liskov Substitution Principle, or, in other words, `SomeInst` is not allowed to be a subtype of `SomeClass`.

Note that this is actually not new. This was already known in the 1960s even before Barbara Liskov formulated the LSP, these are just the standard subtyping rules for functions:

- functions are contravariant in their parameter types
- functions are covariant in their return types